# Docker container bloat

Tags: node.js, ruby, docker, alpine-linux

My image went from 700mb several months ago to 1GB, then steadily grew to 1.7GB. I'm not the only one using it so I don't have complete knowledge of what all was added and when.

The image is based on ruby 2.5.3

```
FROM ruby:2.5.3

#and includes
apt-get install build-essential libpq-dev
#and
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I tried rebuilding the container in Alpine and I'm still getting one that is 1.3GB so it must be something we're doing.

My app directory is

```
688.5M  app
```

The biggest thing in there is

```
320M    node_modules
```

I tried bashing into the container to use du, but I can't really see anything huge, this is the biggest

```
573.5M  usr
```

I am open to general suggestions on how I might prune 1 GB of space from my containers (either the ubuntu based one or the alpine one)

Comment: It looks like your app exceeds 1GB in size, so shrinking your image should probably start there. We need the full Dockerfile if you want advice on how to improve that.

Comment: You can try yarn 2, which get rid of node_modules, can reduce about 100-200 MB.But the rest of app still too large, try figure out is there any useless cache or redurent build stuff. You tagged alpine but you don't use alpine as base image.